# Element well in periodic table

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, orbitals, elements

It may be a very stupid question, but still. Given a periodic table

[image]

Why there is a well/hole of missing elements in atop of periodic table ?
(Pictured as green area). Is this just a side-effect of standard element distribution logic in a table ? Can something be put in these missing places, like different isotopes of elements ? I understand that last pair of rows needs to be put somewhere, because elements without a group are kind of "heretical". But just an empty space in a periodic table feels a bit weird, like some elements are missing or that some are "forbidden".

**EDIT**

BTW, interesting fact,- in that hole above there's a $36$ empty element places in total and there are $28$ elements in total without a group assigned to them (last pair of rows). So these last two rows would fit perfectly in that hole above. Maybe it *can mean* that these last rows **have some group** in reality ? Or that periodic table may be re-structured more optimally.

Comment: Those last two rows - the lanthanides and actinides - *do* have a place. There is a small star where they belong. They are just placed below in usual drawings to not make the table too too long. This means that the "gap" you are talking about is even larger than what is sketched here.

Comment: Also note that we do not list isotopes in the periodic table of elements. The elements in this table are ordered by their *number of protons* or *number of electrons* (that's the same for ideal, neutral elements), which is the atomic number that thye are numbered by. Not by their *number of neutrons*. And isotopes are charaterised by having the same number of protons/electrons but a different number of neutrons. An element may show up in our world in various isotopes - all these isotopes are still the same element.

Comment: _Those last two rows - the lanthanides and actinides - do have a place. There is a small star where they belong_ Yes, but doesn't that in principle will make a mentioned hole **wider** ? If so, that doesn't answers my question at all. Your note about isotopes are correct, however it doesn't answer my question, of **why** there is that hole and if can it be filled **somehow**, by re-structuring periodic table by different order, making elements evenly distributed in table.

Comment: Sure, my comments are also not answers. Just comments to what I read as misconceptions in the question.

Comment: There are no misconceptions in the question at all. Question is only about how to fill that missing hole and "more optimal elements ordering scheme". You are just too attached to current periodic table ordering algorithm, it doesn't have to be like so. There are plenty of alternative schemes like "[two-dimensional spiral (Benfey, 1964)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_periodic_tables#/media/File:Elementspiral_(polyatomic).svg)". Question is, can scheme  be ordered in different rectangular way, but just without holes ?

Comment: From the question text: "*Can something be put in these missing places, like different isotopes of elements ?*" This to me suggests a misconception/misunderstanding of what isotopes mean. Each element only occurs once in the table, regardless of its number of isotopes. That's all I was commenting on.

Comment: @Steeven I understand completely. But number of neutrons in nucleus is not main issue here. Just about how to order table without holes in it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The periodic table is arranged in vertical columns called *groups*  and horizontal rows called *periods*. As you have noticed, different rows contain different numbers of elements, and the the columns are arranged so that there are gaps in the middle of the rows. Why is this ?

The electrons that surround the atoms of each element are arranged into layers called *shells*. There is a fixed maximum number of electrons in each shell. The innermost shell can contain at most two electrons, which is why the first row only contains two elements, hydrogen (atomic number $1$) and helium (atomic number $2$). The maximum number of electrons in each shell increases as you go outwards from the nucleus, which is why the rows become longer as you move down the table - rows $2$ and $3$ contain $8$ elements each, and rows $4$ and $5$ contain $18$ elements each.

So why are there gaps in the rows ? Why not shuffle all the cells in each row to the left hand side, so that for example helium is above beryllium. After all, both of these elements contain two electrons in their outermost shell.

The columns are arranged so that elements with similar chemical behaviours line up in the same column. And it turns out that the most important single factor that determines the chemical behaviour of an element is not how many electrons are in the outermost shell, but how close the outermost shell of electrons is to being a complete shell.

Hydrogen  has similar chemical behaviour to lithium and sodium because all of these elements have just one electron in their outermost shell. So we put hydrogen, lithium and sodium in the same group, which is the left hand column. But helium, with two electrons in its outermost shell, has similar chemical behaviour to neon and argon, with eight electrons in their outermost shells, because all of these elements have a full outermost shell. So we put helium, lithium and argon in the same group, which is the right hand column.

We are used to this "traditional" design for the periodic table, but it is not the only possible design. Various alternative designs have been proposed - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_periodic_tables) for a summary. In particular, French engineer Charles Janet proposed a "left-step" arrangement which avoids the gaps in the rows. In Janet's left-step arrangement, helium *does* sit immediately above beryllium.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @Gert Thank you.